# Mysql FROM_UNIXTIME as UTC

Tags: mysql, timezone

How can i get

```
FROM_UNIXTIME
```

as UTC/GMT in mysql? The date is returned in the timezone of the connection.

I don't want to change the timezone of the connection.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You would be better off setting the time zone ahead of time:

```
SET time_zone='UTC';
select FROM_UNIXTIME(1277942400);
```

The reason is that conversions involving a local time zone can be lossy.  There is an example of this in the [docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) (see the 4th paragraph under the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` section starting with "Note:")

Comment: `SET time_zone = '+00:00'` worked for me. See Mārtiņš Radiņš answer if you want it to be preserved.

Comment: Oh, lovely, so to see the timestamp in a specific timezone: `SET time_zone='America/Los_Angeles';` `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(inserted_at) FROM activity;`

Comment: Note that this doesn't fit OP's requirement "I don't want to change the time zone of the connection."

Comment: Agreed.  [Wutzebaer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276768/mysql-from-unixtime-as-utc/18276813#18276813) is much better than mine.  It should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: Do I need to re set the time_zone after running the query or does it not get stored?

Comment: @Haddock-san this just sets it for the current session, so not "stored" anywhere.

Answer (score 27):

my solution was

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1277942400), @@session.time_zone,'UTC')
```

if CONVERT_TZ returns null, make sure the timezone table of mysql is filled:

```
zypper install mysql-community-server-tools
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Comment: I like the statelessness of the solution

Comment: What a great solution :)

Comment: it's stateless, but fails with ambiguous dates, as conver_ttz can't know the timezone offset of the source timestamp.

Comment: What @MarcLehmann says is true, but note that the ambiguity only lasts one hour per year in timezones using DST. This might be a problem, or not, depending on your business.

Comment: Could be great if it didn't return null

Comment: @stevemoretz did you read the part "if CONVERT_TZ returns null" ?

Comment: @wutzebaer yes I did.but I don't have access to server to run the command

Comment: Awesome solution @wutzebaer

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered but still I'd like to contribute:

If you wan't your server to produce UTC timezone time with functions like `NOW()` and `FROM_UNIXTIME()` etc., you have to set the `time_zone` like @Matt Johnson said.

There's a thing he didn't mention: `SET time_zone = timezone;` sets the timezone for the current connection only.
Use `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00'` if you want these functions to return/convert your dates in UTC by default so you didn't have to set the timezone every time you want to save some UTC based dates.

Check your current time_zone settings: `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: 10.6 MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot control the timezone of your session<sup>*</sup>, `from_unixtime`, `now`, `current_date`, etc. are fundamentally broken and should be avoided.  Fortunately, date arithmetic completely ignores session timezone, so you can simply do:

```
select '1970-01-01' + interval 1277942400 second
```

or the equivalent

```
select date_add('1970-01-01', interval 1277942400 second)
```

<sup><sup>*</sup> this can be hard; some clients "helpfully" will set a session timezone for you based on environment; other clients will automatically reestablish a dropped connection so you can't rely on setting timezone just when you connect and must set it with every statement</sup>

In place of `now()`/`current_date()`, use `utc_timestamp()`/`date(utc_timestamp())` (converting to some timezone with convert_tz if desired).

Answer (score 0):

if you are lazy like me and don't want to change global session timezone variables (moved to another server, forgot to change that there and hop, you are in troubles), session variables (used some module autoreconnecting to db and hop, your variable issued at connection is gone) and don't wish to load time zone stuff then i suppose this might help :).

```
select 
  now() as timezoned,
  date_add(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(0), interval 
      unix_timestamp()+TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),UTC_TIMESTAMP()) SECOND
  ) as utc
```

and it's going to work even with negative timestamps. and if you need to convert a specific column, just replace unix_timestamp() with your column containing the timestamp.

as a bonus, if you need to find a difference between datetime and now, while the column is in unix_timestamp (say, "utc"), just wrap it with TIMESTAMPdiff(SECOND, .., NOW()) and the day is saved :).

update: if you live in a region with a time savings and your time jumps, here is a thing i came up with, which is a much more simple one.

select
from_unixtime(1277942400) as timezoned,
date_add(
'1970-01-01 00:00:00', interval
1277942400 SECOND
) as utc

much more simple :).

an alternative that is not so good:

select
from_unixtime(1277942400) as timezoned,
date_add(
FROM_UNIXTIME(0), interval
1277942400+
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-1-2')-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(0)-24*3600)
SECOND
) as utc

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve with adding the timestampdiff; can you explain in detail?  this doesn't seem to be correct.  for instance, with a session timezone of America/Los_Angeles, `date_add(     FROM_UNIXTIME(0), interval       1277942400+TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),UTC_TIMESTAMP()) SECOND   )` gives `2010-06-30 23:00:00`, not `2010-07-01 00:00:00` right now

Comment: that's because you live in a place with a jumpy time :). you have +/- hour and since you are in a summer time mode right now, the time shift for your zone is different. this is an old post and i don't remember much, so sorry if i'm not understanding you correctly, but you need to get utc date, right?