# PHP - mktime store wrong date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp, mktime

When I store the date through `FROM_UNIXTIME()` the date stores one day before.
My debug code:

```
$date = date("m-d-Y", time());

$date_unix = explode('-', $date);

if (count($date_unix) == 3) {
    list ( $m, $d, $y ) = $date_unix;
    $date_unix = mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
}

echo "<br />Date: " . $date;
echo "<br />Date after mktime: " . $date_unix;
echo "<br />Date manual mktime: " . date("m-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,8,18,2014));
```

I'm using the date from the server, change it to a unixtime with `mktime()` and trying to store in the database with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

```
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$sql = "INSERT INTO data ( data ) VALUES ( FROM_UNIXTIME(:date_unix) )";
$st = $conn->prepare($sql);
$st->bindValue(":date_unix", $date_unix, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->execute();
```

And after all this mess, the mysql still stores the date in the day before.

> Ex: today is 08/18/2014 and in the database is 2014-08-17

The date_default_timezone in the server is "America/Cuiaba" and nothing change if I change the timezone.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do with that date? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: SQL's time/date format (DATETIME) far as I know, is stored a `YYYY-MM-DD` and you're using `m-d-Y`

Comment: I'm using the unixtime to store `FROM_UNIXTIME()` after making a `mktime()`

Comment: @JohnConde I'm doubting you're gonna touch this one, even with a 20-foot pole ;) Even Father Time's gotta take a breather every once in a while. *They can't all be saved.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Although I suspect you're comment recognizes the crux of the issue, the fact that they can't articulate what they are trying to do makes this impossible to answer. It's a shame because it probably is a really simple issue.

Comment: @JohnConde You're right John; it makes it all that more difficult. If we knew what the OP wants to achieve as the *ultimate goal*, then most likely a solution could be given; not to mention a simpler method. *Nice go on the crux* ;) Did the butler do it? We'll probably never know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- *crux* is a word not used often enough. *Behoove*  is another. :)

Comment: @JohnConde I'm definitely putting that one in my TOP 50 favorite and intriguing words ;) *Crux & Behoove* - Sounds like what a Superhero would say before taking off. "Yoinks & away" has always been my favorite.

Comment: Uh-oh, the Canadian learned a new word ... Evening @Fred-ii- :)

Comment: Afternoon @TheBlueDog yah, I'm a linguistic hound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix timestamps are UTC by definition. However, MySQL's FROM_UNIXTIME [implicitly converts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) a unix timestamp into the MySQL server's timezone (which is a completely different setting than PHP's `default_date_timezone` setting).

The *America/Cuiaba* timezone is UTC - 4 hours, so the date "2014-08-18 00:00:00 (UTC)" is actually 2014-08-17 20:00:00 (America/Cuiaba)" -- thus the apparent 1-day difference.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18276813/1995300) on how to convert between timezones in your MySQL database.

Comment: If I store a DATETIME with hours and minutes will fix the issue? Because when I do `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())` in the mysql server, the date it's equal to the clock.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())` will just return the local time, because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` creates a UTC representation of the current time, and `FROM_UNIXTIME` then converts it back from UTC to local time. You can store any date/time in a `DATETIME` column and MySQL wont's store (or imply) any timezone information with it. Depending on your requirements, it might be better to simply store dates as UTC dates and convert them to the appropriate timezone in your frontend into the user's local time.