# FROM_UNIXTIME returning one extra hour

Tags: mysql

I got an extremely simple need :
convert some milliseconds values to "##:##:##" (hours/minutes/seconds) format.

It appears FROM_UNIXTIME can do the job, so I used it, but...

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(42, "%H:%i:%s") AS pony
    ,FROM_UNIXTIME(3702, "%H:%i:%s") AS unicorn
```

returns

```
pony       unicorn
01:00:42   02:01:42
```

With no timezone setting in this function, I don't know how to remove this extra (wtf) hour.

*removing 3600 seconds produces a negative value, which outputs a NULL*

I guess I should use another way, but if I have to use half a dozen converts, I could as well do it manually...  is there nothing **simple and efficient** ?

---

*I don't have an exact MySQL version, but I need a minimum of portability anyway. Something working with, say MySQL 5.x
Do I need to make my calculations manually ?*

---

EDIT : 
*Opted for an ugly, but working "solution" :*

```
CONCAT(
  LPAD(FLOOR((my_column/1000) / 3600), 2, '0'), ':',
  LPAD(FLOOR(((my_column/1000) % 3600) / 60), 2, '0'), ':',
  LPAD(FLOOR((my_column/1000) % 60), 2, '0')) AS time
```

Outputs with desired format. *examples "03:12:04" or "123:00:44"*

Comment: My guess would be that that is your local time zone. Maybe using `SET time_zone='UTC';` helps, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18276768/5520354

Comment: @C14L Yeah, I'm sure it's because of those ******* daylightssavings (Im FR), but for now, trying to set the timezone only... turned all my results to **null**.  Also, 'UTC" didnt seem to be a valide value (produced an error), had to use '+00:00'.  Shall it explain the nulls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to opt for an ugly, but working "solution" :

```
CONCAT(
  LPAD(FLOOR((my_column/1000) / 3600), 2, '0'), ':',
  LPAD(FLOOR(((my_column/1000) % 3600) / 60), 2, '0'), ':',
  LPAD(FLOOR((my_column/1000) % 60), 2, '0')) AS time
```

Outputs with desired format. examples "*03:12:04*" or "*123:00:44*"

C14L's comment should be a better choice, but it only made things worse :/

Please, post an answer if you have something reliable and easier to use.  
Having to making such calculations manually just doesn't make sense to me.